# Error al iniciar sesion en MySql database server en webmin

Tags: mysql

como puedo resolver este problema?... cree una conexion en webmin, pero cuando quiero acceder al MySql database de webmin, me muestra un mensaje con una falla de inicio... puse la contraseña de mi root y la de mysql y aun no puedo iniciar sesion, les agredeceria su respuesta. Gracias..[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes cambiar el cifrado de la contraseña del usuario alterando el usuario con el siguiente comando Alter:

> ALTER USER 'username'@'ip_address' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';

Podemos evitar este error haciendo que funcione con el antiguo complemento de contraseña:

Primero cambie el complemento de autenticación en el archivo my.cnf para el archivo Linux **/ my.ini** en Windows.

> [mysqld]
>
> default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password

Reinicia el servidor mysql para tomar los cambios en efecto e intenta conectarte a través de MySQL con cualquier cliente mysql.

Si aún no puede conectarse y obtiene el siguiente error:

```
Unable to load plugin 'caching_sha2_password'
```

Significa que su usuario necesita el complemento anterior. Por lo tanto, intente crear un nuevo usuario con el usuario create o el comando grant luego de cambiar el plugin predeterminado. entonces el nuevo usuario necesita el complemento nativo y podrá conectarse a MySQL.

Autor de la respuesta :[aman aggarwal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3118651/aman-aggarwal)

la pregunta original es : [authentication plugin caching sha2 password cannot be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded)